# Use threading in a function to return and manipulate data

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that uses threading to connect to a number of network devices and runs commands against them

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Importing Netmiko modules
from netmiko import Netmiko
from netmiko.ssh_exception import (
    NetMikoAuthenticationException,
    NetMikoTimeoutException,
)

import signal, os, json, re

# Queuing and threading libraries
from queue import Queue
import threading


class MyFunction:
    def __init__(self):

        # Get the password
        self.password = "password"

        # Switch IP addresses from text file that has one IP per line
        self.hops = ["switch1", "switch2", "switch3"]
        self.hop_info = []

        # Set up thread count for number of threads to spin up
        self.num_threads = 8
        # This sets up the queue
        self.enclosure_queue = Queue()
        # Set up thread lock so that only one thread prints at a time
        self.print_lock = threading.Lock()

        self.command = "show ip route 127.0.0.1 | json"

    def deviceconnector(self, i, q):

        while True:

            # and aren't required
            print("{}: Waiting for IP address...".format(i))
            ip = q.get()
            print("{}: Acquired IP: {}".format(i, ip))

            # k,v passed to net_connect
            device_dict = {
                "host": ip,
                "username": "admin",
                "password": self.password,
                "device_type": "cisco_ios",
            }

            try:
                net_connect = Netmiko(**device_dict)
            except NetMikoTimeoutException:
                with self.print_lock:
                    print("\n{}: ERROR: Connection to {} timed-out.\n".format(i, ip))
                q.task_done()
                continue
            except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
                with self.print_lock:
                    print(
                        "\n{}: ERROR: Authenticaftion failed for {}. Stopping script. \n".format(
                            i, ip
                        )
                    )
                q.task_done()

            output = net_connect.send_command(self.command)

            with self.print_lock:
                print("{}: Printing output...".format(i))
                print(output)

            # Disconnect from device
            net_connect.disconnect

            q.task_done()


    def main(self):

        for i in range(len(self.hops)):
            thread = threading.Thread(
                target=self.deviceconnector, args=(i, self.enclosure_queue)
            )
            # Set the thread as a background daemon/job
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            # Start the thread
            thread.start()

        for hop in self.hops:
            self.enclosure_queue.put(hop)

        # Wait for all tasks in the queue to be marked as completed (task_done)
        self.enclosure_queue.join()
        print("*** Script complete")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Calling the main function
    run = Trace()
    run.main()
```

This prints the output of the commands fine but instead of printing the output, I want to do the threading in a function so the returned data can be manipulated and used as part of another function. I can't seem to get the threading functionality in main() to allow this.

Update
I'm using this in an api endpoint so taking out the
if **name** == "**main**":

and calling it from another a main.py. The problem I'm having is that it hangs and doesn't return but can't quite figure out why. It only hangs when ran from main.py, not when if has the **main** function.

Answer (score 0):

You are already writing the data to your `Queue`, so you just have to get them back from there

```
my_data = q.get()
```

Did you write the code? If so, use your Queue :)